# How to create Close Button in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I try to create side menu in react native with createDrawerNavigator (React Navigation), it's success, but I get a problem when create close button in top right side of screen like image bellow (red circle)

[image]

Please help me to create like that in react native with createDrawerNavigator (React Navigation).
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Answer (score 0):

You can close a drawer navigator using `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer()`.

[Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html)

Comment: They want to draw a button, so they don't need the code to close just yet :)

Comment: ya, I want to draw the button